# How can I see the source code for a python library?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I currently find myself using the bs4/BeautifulSoup library a lot in python, and have recently been wondering how it works. I would love to see the source code for the library and don't know how. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to ask the module itself. Usually its all you need

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__file__
'/home/td/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py'
>>> exit()
$ pushd /home/td/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4
$ ls
builder    diagnose.py  __init__.py  testing.py
dammit.py  element.py   __pycache__  tests
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any IDE, you can right click on imported line and goto Implementation.
Otherwise you can find the source code in `<python_installtion_path>\Lib\site-packages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the location where python is installed and inside the python folder, you will have a folder called Lib you can find all the packages there open the required python file you will get the code.

example location: C:\Python38\Lib